# Getting a java.util.zip.ZipException when trying to create a ZipFile in JAVA?

Tags: java, zip

I am getting this error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
```

and I am not quite sure what is the problem, when I search google for `CEN` header nothing useful is found.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code and it fails on the last line:

```
ZipFile resourceZip = null;
if (pir.getSource().endsWith("Resources.zip")) 
{
    File temp = new File( "C:\\Users\\nbonnet\\Desktop\\new\\Resources1.zip");
    byte[] bytesFromClob = ClobHelper.bytesFromClob(pir.getContents(),"latin1");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
    out.write(bytesFromClob);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    resourceZip = new ZipFile(temp);  // <-- Code fails here
}
```

Comment: What is the code you are running?

Comment: Did you see this page http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/invalid-cen-header which states that the error may be caused by a zip file containing an entry larger than 4GB in size.

Comment: Also this page http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6432010 which suggests that the compression method used to create the zip is not supported by the JDK.

Comment: I added the code I am running. Also I am 100% sure the file is less than 4GB. As far as the compression ... is there a workaround? Can i tell it to do some other compression?

Comment: Why are you storing binary data in a CLOB? I would suggest that you compare the data that you're reading from the database with the data that you're putting into it. I'll bet they're different.

Comment: They aren't .. goes in as a ZIP with a bunch of information in it and when I read it back I get it all back in the same format and such

Comment: Well there are 3 possibilities.  Either your original is corrupted, it got corrupted writing it to the database, or it got corrupted reading it from the database.  I suggest you check all three.

Comment: These files are accessed somewhere else in a different way (i.e. we don't try to go through them the user can directly download them) and they are not corrupt. So that is why I have posted and believe it is how I am creating the Zip ...and my incompetence in File IO

Comment: @nick - can you read the original file using ZipFile? The way you're going to solve this problem is separate the steps of retrieving from the database and opening as a zip. If you can open the original file as a zip, then you know that your problem is reading from the database. Perhaps your ClobHelper doesn't read all the bytes. Or perhaps there's a conversion error.

Comment: I know that it is at least working for some of the things with zips because below the code I have shown I am populating a Map with values found in files inside the zip and that is working fine. If anyone knows of any sources that have an example of getting a CLOB from a DB and back to a Zip it'd be awesome and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You're writing the file as a regular (non-ZIP) file and then trying to read it back as a ZIP file.  That's not going to work.  You need to write it with a `ZipOutputStream`.

Check out [this example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/CreateZip.html) or [this one](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util.zip/how-to-write-zip-file.html).

Comment: Right.  There's nothing in the code above that would create a zip file.

Comment: I have tried that but then I get this error:

java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry

But the whole reason I am writing it out to a zip is because I need to see the entries. I believe it throws this because I am not using out.putNextEntry()..

Comment: @Keith - that's one interpretation. Another is that the data in the database is in ZIP format. Of course, as I noted in my comment, it's strange that the data is coming from a CLOB rather than a BLOB.

Comment: @kdgregory: true, that's another possibility.  If so, the header of the file is getting corrupted somehow (character set conversion?).

Comment: Possibly character set conversion, or perhaps the CLOB is rejecting any 0 bytes. I figured I gave the OP enough of a hint ... I suspect there are worse problems to come.

Comment: I have seen the first example, which has led me in the direction I have gone in. But I am trying out the second example now. Is there a way of creating a ZipEntry from my byte[]?... so then i can use out.putEntry()

Comment: sad that the links are now broken